# How to design radio buttons for multiple paragraphs?

Tags: javascript, css, html, user-interface

I'm trying to set radio buttons for large paragraphs choices with multiple lines.

But how do I make the radio button appear not at the beginning but as I mentioned in the image.

I am able to divide the elements in the list with lines  but the radio buttons are actually coming at the beginning of the element just like normal letter in a text. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJje7.jpg)

Here is the code that I've tried for list items

```
<ul>
    <span>
        <input type="radio" name="pokemon1" required>
        <b>AT&ampT SOUTHWEST</b></br>
        <p>Multiple lines text</p>
        </div>
    </span>
    <hr/ style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px;">
    <span>
        <input type="radio" name="pokemon1" required>
        <b>AT&ampT SOUTHWEST</b></br>
        <p>Multiple lines text</p>
    </span>
    <hr/ style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px;">
    <span>
        <input type="radio" name="pokemon1" required>
        <b>AT&ampT SOUTHWEST</b></br>
        <p>Multiple lines text</p>
    </span>
    <hr/ style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px;">
    <span>
        <input type="radio" name="pokemon1" required>
        <b>AT&ampT SOUTHWEST</b></br>
        <p>Multiple lines text</p>
    </span>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zeGVRB)

---

I would first use a more meaningful markup, using a `<label for="...">` element, keeping the style off from the markup and removing the `<hr>` element, like so

```
<fieldset>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="rb1" name="rb" />
      <label for="rb1">This label <br>is 3 lines <br />long</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="rb2" name="rb" />
      <label for="rb2">This label <br>is 4 <br />lines <br />long</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="rb3" name="rb" />
      <label for="rb3">This label <br>is 3 lines <br />long</label>
    </li>
  </ul> 
</fieldset>
```

since all the radioboxes should belong to a single `fieldset` and you have a `list` of radioboxes. The vertical alignment could easily be done using `Flexbox` on the list-items, by displacing elements by `rows` and setting a `center` alignment for the cross-axis

```
fieldset li { 
  padding: 20px; 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px #ddd solid;  }

fieldset label {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 30px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe fcalderan has given the best answer already - he even gave you the CSS.

Just to reiterate his point. You use the label tag to label your inputs. You can then use the 'for' attribute like this: 'for="place-id-of-input-here"' within your label, to point the label to the input. This makes the label clickable (you can click the text as well as clicking the radio button). Also, you can target the two parts of your input separately, the input and the label (like fcalderan has done).

Hope this helps, J.